# Helm follow mode for sorted list of text files

Tags: helm

I need to browse lots of text files and want to use helm follow mode to preview the files without leaving the helm session.

To do so I tried `helm-find-files` which lets me sort the candidates alphabetically or by modification time (I need both). However in helm-find-files the [follow mode only works for images and not for text files](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/2546).

As a workaround I tried to use `helm-find` instead, which seems to work with text files. However in this case I am not able to sort the candidate list.

Do you have a suggestion for a better workaround?

**Edit**
I also tried just to comment out the lines added in commit [2672e24](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/commit/243761ac8f951c924a7486fc0b2a51e84886c672) in `helm-files` (and deleting the elc file since byte compilation didn't work for me).

```
(unless image-cand
      (when follow
        (helm-follow-mode -1)
        (cl-return-from helm-find-files-persistent-action
          (message "Helm-follow-mode allowed only on images, disabling"))))
```

Now this works, but that's very dirty. So there must be a better workaround I guess.

Comment: Unfortunately `helm-find-files-persistent-action-if` is very complicated and would not work with `helm-follow-mode`, hence (I assume) the commit you mention in the GitHub issue.  Do you only want to browse a list of files or do you need the entire machinery including directory navigation?

Comment: In this case I need to browse only a list of files matching a pattern.